# Haiving a problem to Paginate an iteration with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, kaminari

I'm trying to paginate a result of an iteration using Kaminari. The pagination is showing well but its not cutting it into another page. All is showing on the same page even when I click on page 2, it still the same result as page 1

I'm using rails 6 and ruby 2.5

in my controller i have this

```rb
def dashboard
    user_gigs = current_user.gigs
    @user_gigs_pager = Kaminari.paginate_array(user_gigs).page(params[:page]).per(4)
  end
```

then in my view I call the paginate

```rb
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header-title is-centered">
     <%= paginate @user_gigs_pager %>
   </div>
</div>
```

this my full view code

```rb
 <% current_user.gigs.each do |gig| %>
                  <%# <% user_gigs = current_user.gigs  %>
                    <div class="column is-one-third">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-image">
                              <%= link_to edit_gig_path(gig) do %>
                                <figure class="image is-4by3">
                                    <!-- Gig Cover Image Here -->
                                    <%= image_tag gig_cover(gig) %>
                                </figure>
                              <% end %>
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-content p-t-5 p-b-5">
                                <p class="subtitle is-6 m-b-5"><%= link_to gig.title.truncate(20), gig_path(gig) %></p>
                                <span class="star-review"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                  <%= gig.average_rating %> <span class="star-review">(<%= gig.reviews.count %>)</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <footer class="card-footer">
                              <p class="deletegig">
                                <%= link_to destroy_gig_path(gig), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "are you sure"} do  %>
                                  <span class="icon has-text-danger">
                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                  </span>
                                <% end %>
                              </p>
                               <% basic_price = gig.pricings.find{ |p| p.pricing_type == 'basic' }%>
                                <a class="has-text-danger is-block card-footer-item has-text-right">
                                  <% if !basic_price.nil? %>
                                    <span class="small-title">Points</span> <i class="fab fa-bitcoin"></i>
                                    <strong><%=  basic_price.price %></strong>
                                  <% else %>
                                    <strong>
                                      <span class="small-title has-text-dark">Pas de point</span>
                                    </strong>
                                  <% end %>
                                </a>
                            </footer>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                  <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header-title is-centered">
                <%= paginate @user_gigs_pager %>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Kaminari.paginate_array(user_gigs).page(params[:page]).per(4)`

expects page number as argument of `page` and number of records per page as argument of `per`.

Your `params` must contain page number (i.e. 1 or 2 or 3 ...) in `:page` key.

Comment: Can you give me an example with a snippet of code please ?

Comment: Just do this: Inspect the params in controller before pagination line after you click for page 2. What is params[:page] value? It must be 1 every time which is causing the issue. It actually should be according to the page you click.

Comment: If you know how to inspect/pry then good, otherwise you can use this gem, it is great: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Comment: I'm gettting this with the debug

```ruby
NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x007ff72845b380>):
```

Comment: Double-check syntax of this line in controller when debugging: `Kaminari.paginate_array(user_gigs).page(params[:page]).per(4)`. You may have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to apply the **pagination** on the **ActiveRecord association** instead of the **array**.

So in my controller it should be

```rb
 @user_gigs_pager = current_user.gigs.page(params[:page]).per(4)
```

then in the view

```rb
<% @user_gigs_pager.each do |gig| %>
....

<%= paginate @user_gigs_pager %>
```